# Spring Data Neo4j 6: findAll() operation doesn't map relationships properly

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

In Spring Data Neo4j 6 (6.0.1), a basic Neo4jTemplate findAll() operation with a simple relationship doesn't seem to map the relationship entity and its target even though they are part of the result set. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Let's consider the following basic scenario:

```
var a = new EntityA();
var b = new EntityB();
a.entityB = b;

neo4jTemplate.save(a);
```

with

```
@Node
public class EntityA {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    public String id;

    @Relationship("HAS_ENTITY_B")
    public EntityB entityB;
}

@Node
public class EntityB {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(UUIDStringGenerator.class)
    public String id;
}
```

When trying to map a result like this:

```
var result = neo4jTemplate.findAll("MATCH (a:EntityA)-[r:HAS_ENTITY_B]->(b:EntityB) RETURN a,r,b", EntityA.class);
Assert.notNull(result.get(0).entityB, "entityB should not be null here!");
```

I would expect the entityB property not to be null.

Answer (score 1):

That's certainly not the expected behavior, but you should write your query this way:

```
MATCH (a:EntityA)-[r:HAS_ENTITY_B]->(b:EntityB) RETURN a, COLLECT(r), COLLECT(b)
```

For now, it looks like there is a lack of documentation and implementation regarding custom queries and relationships in SDN 6 (see [this ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/pull/2101) and [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2034)).